# Visual Studio Team Services Rest API - How to get 'TeamContext'?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to build a widget for Visual studio team services dashboard.

When calling APIs from Visual Studio's rest clients, many API requires an 'TeamContext' as input. For example:

```
IPromise<void> deleteTeamIteration(teamContext, id)
```

But how do I get 'TeamContext'? I tried:

```
var teamContext = VSS.getWebContext().team;
```

but it turns out there are two types of TeamContexts (detailed below). `VSS.getWebContext.team` gives the first kind. While the APIs expect the second kind.

How do I get the second kind of teamContext?

**First Kind of TeamContext:**

https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/vss/references/sdk_interfaces/teamcontext

[image]

**Second Kind of TeamContext:**

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/core/contracts/teamcontext

[image]

**EDIT: 
A work around is to construct the second type of TeamContext myself.**

```
var teamContext2 = {
    project : VSS.getWebContext().project.name,
    projectId : VSS.getWebContext().project.id,
    team : VSS.getWebContext().team.name,
    teamId : VSS.getWebContext().team.id
};
```

It's not the most elegant thing, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around is the right way to get it. Refer to this link from MSDN for details: [Developing the widget](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2016/02/01/developing-the-widget/).

```
var teamContext: TFS_Core_Contracts.TeamContext = { projectId: webContext.project.id, teamId: webContext.team.id, project: "", team: "" };
```

Comment: A "work around" doesn't sound like it's the right way to do it 